# Data visualization with Virtual Earth and SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, virtual-earth

Scenario:  I have a list of addresses (they have already been converted to lat/long) and the conference that the person attended.

What I want:  I want to add a circle shape to a Virtual Earth map that covers, let's say, 90% of the attendees to a conference.  I will repeat this for each conference.  This will show me how much the different conference "attendance areas" overlap each other.  The reason for the 90& is to exclude the "outliers", those that aren't in the main "attendance area".

So the question:  What is the algorithm or SQL spatial query do get the above data set (the 90%)?  I think I can take it from there (ie. how big to make the circle, where to place it, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each person, total the distances to all other people. 
Sort by these totals, and remove the highest 10%.

Then take to two remaining people that are farthest apart, and place your center there. The distance between the farthest people is your diameter.